# How does one feed pavana deva?

Tags: gods

Agni is considered the mouth of the gods and goddesses and the medium that conveys offerings to them in a homa (votive ritual)

How does one feed pavana deva ?

Comment: What do you mean by "How does one feed pavana deva ?" ? You have your answer in your question itself if I understood correctly.

Comment: Ahuti given in Homa in the name of Vayu Deva (i.e using specific mantra for Vayu) will reach him. If one is doing a Puja of Vayu then when we offer Naivedya he is supposed to eat it.